# Adding OpenID to my AppEngine site? how users create an account?

Tags: google-app-engine, openid

Hi I am about to start using OpenID to login my users. I am ok the login process and it looks pretty simple.

But I don't know how the user registration works, when an user click on the Sign-in or register link, what happens ? Do I need to create my own OpenID Provider ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User needs to have an account with [one of the OpenID providers](http://openid.net/get-an-openid/). The whole point of OpenID is that users can have one account and use it to login to all sites supporting OpenID.

Comment: I got that, but what about users that don't ? how can I provide them  an account creation option ?

Comment: Either a custom account handling, i.e. register/confirm-email/login (= more coding), or direct user to open account with one of the specialized  OpenID providers, like https://www.myopenid.com/